# How to change in the Magento DB the prices of the product

Tags: magento

I've troubles to figure out how to change the prices of a product in the magento DB.
I tryed to change the prices in the catalog_product_index_price table but the price doesn't change.

Comment: You need to read more about the eav model in magento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a website [here](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/update-prices-sql/) that explains it in more detail, but the short answer is that you need to change the price in the **catalog_product_entity_decimal** table and then reindex Product Prices in the backend (and potentially Product Flat Data as well)

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses variety of indexing and caching methods that make simply changing the value directly in the database not a good idea.

If you look, you can see the prices are also defined in the Price Index tables:

**catalog_product_index_price_idx**

And also the flat tables (if you use them):

**catalog_product_flat_1** (number 1 depends on store)

If you're trying to mass update prices, I recommend either using a tool such as [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) or the built in Magento import methods to update prices.  Directly modifying the database is generally not a good idea with Magento, given it's complex database structure.